# Anchor and Bookmark from one page to another. Why doesn't it scroll to bookmark in Page 2?

Tags: html

For example:

**PageA.html**

```
<a href="pageB.html#bottom">Go to Page 2 Bottom</a>
```

**PageB.html**

lots of breaks so that the hyperlink is towards the bottom with lots of vertical scroll.

```
<br/><br/><br/>...<a name="bottom">bottom of page</a>
```

When I click the link of PageA, I want it to go to PageB, but end up with the bottom A scrolled into view, but it doesn't.  I'm sure it is something very simple.

Comment: Your exact code -- cut and pasted from this page -- is working for me on FireFox.  But I notice you seem to have either an extra or unencoded '>' character in your link text on PageA.  I'd say replace 'Page 2 Bottom>' with 'Page 2 Bottom&gt;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id to your tag next to name.

Page A:

```
 <a href="pagename.hml#anchor">link text</a>
```

Page B:

```
 <a name="anchor" id="anchor">paragraph</a>
```

But ive tried your code and my code and they both work which is weird.

**PK**

Comment: adding the additional id attribute, in addition to name did it.  Thanks